# How to set the selected option of <select>

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get my select option to show the selected category from my DB in the dropdown. I can only get it to show it, when i hit my submit button.

```
<?php

    (isset($_POST["kategori"])) ? $kategori = $_POST["kategori"] : $kategori=1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kategori" 
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while($produkt = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

?>

 <option <?php if ($kategori == $produkt['kategori_id'] ) echo 'selected'; ?> 
 value="<? echo $produkt['kategori_id']; ?>">
 <? echo $produkt['kategori_navn']; ?></option>

<?php
}
?>
```

Apparently I’m getting the value from POST, and that’s why it first shows the category when I hit submit.

I need to make a select from my database with the product ID of the product, and use it’s id to mark which category is set.

And I can’t figure out how to do that.

Comment: Your code seem to be good. Look on data

Comment: It contains the $_POST value and is being used to update the DB "UPDATE produkt SET fk_kategori_id = '$kategori' WHERE produkt_id=$id"

Comment: instead of echo 'selected'; write selected="selected"

Comment: Apparently I’m getting the value from POST, and that’s why it first shows the category when I hit submit.

I need to make a select from my database with the product ID of the product, and use it’s id to mark which category is set.

And I can’t figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kategori" 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($produkt = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

     if ( $kategori == $produkt['kategori_id']  ) : ?>
        <option selected="selected" value="<?=$produkt['kategori_id']; ?>"><?=$produkt['kategori_navn']; ?></option>
     <?php else: ?>
        <option value="<?=$produkt['kategori_id']; ?>"><?=$produkt['kategori_navn']; ?></option>
     <?php endif; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Where `$kategori` is variable which has the previously selected option value.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add like this:

```
  <option <?php if ($kategori == $produkt['kategori_id'] ) ?> value="<? echo $produkt['kategori_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><? echo $produkt['kategori_navn']; ?></option>
```

Comment: All of your outputed options would be selected and only one of themm would have value set.

Comment: he is using condition know,ok i agree, i need to give the detailed explanation....

Answer (score -1):

Try the query like this:
$sql="select * from `kategori` where `kategori_id` IN ($kategori)";

you will automatically get the matched category which you can select it without using while loop

Comment: The OP wants to output all options and select the one which was posted. Your code will output only one option which would make the selection useless.

Comment: That can also be done just firing the another query using NOT... so that the output will contain matched and unmatched options..